# Parsing predicates with slash inside list

Tags: prolog

I have facts such as:

```
timetable(paris, london, [10:00/11:00, 22:00/23:00])
```

How can I know whether a flight exists between two places at a certain hour?

I have tried the following unsucessfull:

```
flight_hour(Hour, [Hour/B|T]).
flight_hour(Hour, [A/B|T]) :- flight_hour(Hour, T).
flight(Place1, Place2, Hour) :- timetable(Place1, Place2, X), flight_hour(Hour, X).
```

What does the slash mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this and specify the structure of the data:

```
timetable(paris, london, [10:00/11:00, 22:00/23:00]).

flight_hour(Hour:Min, Hour:Min/_:_).
flight_hour(Hour, [_:_/_:_,T]) :- 
    flight_hour(Hour, T).
flight(Place1, Place2, Hour):- 
    timetable(Place1, Place2, X), 
    flight_hour(Hour, X).

?- flight(paris,london,T).
T = 22:0 %i don't know if this is the result you want
```